# How to delete data from all the pages of the table using Datatable plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable

I have this table of data where i am using **Datatable** plugin which i want to clear on button click and redraw it with some new values which i get from ajax.The problem is I  am not able to delete data from all the pages. Only the data from first page is emptied.Below is the code which i use..

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$.ajax({ 
    type: "POST", 
    url: "filename.php", 
    dataType: "JSON",
    data: {some_data},       
    success: function(data2)
    { 
        variable=data2;
                //console.log(data2);
        $('#table1').find('td').remove();
        $("#table1").find("tr:gt(0)").remove();
        var cr = data2.length;
                //console.log(cr);
        var i;
        for(i=0;i<cr;i++)
        {
         //Adding data to table here                                
        }
            }
        });//Ajax code ends here 
        });
```

The error in the console shows

***table-datatables-managed.min.js:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: App is not defined
    at table-datatables-managed.min.js:1***

Please Help!

**Updated Full code:**

```
   $.ajax({ 
            type: "POST", 
            url: "getentryforhwtry.php", 
            dataType: "JSON",
            data: {deptselect_val:checkboxes2,
                    blckselect_val:checkboxes,
                    subblckselect_val:subblockcheckboxes,
                    subnetselect_val:ipcheckboxes,
                    filename_val:filename},      
            success: function(data2)
            { 
                variable=data2;
                console.log(data2);
                var otable=$('#table1').dataTable();
                otable.fnClearTable();

                /*$('#table1').find('td').remove();
                $("#table1").find("tr:gt(0)").remove();*/

                var cr = data2.length;
                console.log(cr);
                var i;
        for(i=0;i<cr;i++)
        {

        $('#table1 tr:last').after('<tr class=\'t1\'><td>'+data2[i].uname+'</td><td>'+data2[i].ccode+'</td><td>'+data2[i].roomno+'</td><td>'+data2[i].Sub_block+'</td><td>'+data2[i].ipv4+'</td><td>'+data2[i].ipv6+'</td><td>'+data2[i].jackno+'</td><td>'+data2[i].vlanid+'</td><td>'+data2[i].comments+'</td><td><a href=\"delete.php?uname='+data2[i].uname+'\"><input type=\'submit\' id=\'delete\' value=\'del\' class=\'btn btn-xs purple\' /></a><a href=\"edit.php?uname='+data2[i].uname+'\"><input type=\'submit\' id=\'edit\' value=\'edit\' class=\'btn btn-xs purple\' /></a><a href=\"view.php?uname='+data2[i].uname+'\"><input type=\'submit\' id=\'view\' value=\'view\' class=\'btn btn-xs purple\' /></a></td></tr>');                                      
                    }
            }
        });//Ajax code ends here 
        });
```

**EDIT:**
Resolved It!!. The problem was with *jQuery* conflicting which could be resolved by using the

```
jQuery.noConflict();
```

Thank you.Cheers!!

Answer (score 0):

You can use a function

```
dataTable.fnClearTable();
```

It will clear the tbody of the table and then you can add new rows to datatable.

Documentation link is [here](http://legacy.datatables.net/ref).

### Update

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var oTable = $('#example').dataTable();
  oTable.fnClearTable();
} );
```

Comment: It says: Uncaught TypeError: $(...).fnClearTable is not a function

Comment: which datatable library version are you using? @Mur2za_B

Comment: Also please check update in my answer and try it that way. @Mur2za_B

Comment: DataTables 1.10.11 @Smit Raval

Comment: The updated answer gives the following error: **Uncaught TypeError: $(...).dataTable is not a function**

Comment: Are you sure you have included all files correctly? Can you please show your full code? @Mur2za_B

Comment: where are you adding library? @Mur2za_B

Comment: I have it downloaded

Comment: how do you add it in your html page? Can you please show the sequence of your js files? @Mur2za_B

Comment: <!-- datatables plugins -->
<link href="assets_/global/plugins/datatables/datatables.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="assets_/global/plugins/datatables/plugins/bootstrap/datatables.bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="assets_/global/scripts/datatable.js" type="text/javascript"></script> ...

Comment: <script src="assets_/global/plugins/datatables/datatables.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="assets_/global/plugins/datatables/plugins/bootstrap/datatables.bootstrap.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="assets_/pages/scripts/table-datatables-managed.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<!-- end datatables plugins-->

Comment: Please do check the scripts  @Smit Raval